Is there a more common name for a conical frustum with sphere caps?
Consider the shape in the bottom right, which is the convex hull of 2 spheres with different radii.
It’s a conical frustum with round/sphere caps. I wonder if there is a shorter, more common name. I’ve started to call it a round cone, but that doesn’t feel quite right.


I know of no common name. Looks like a pestle to me.

Yes,  repeated hand  pounding forces on a pestle in a mortar made of rock or ceramic are used to pulverize solids, tablets etc. The two are mentioned together, I do not know a name in English.
